# OpenPop.Pop3 error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect to a exchange server using OpenPop library and when I try to connect it says "Server is not available", this is my code:

```
 Pop3Client Client = new Pop3Client();
            Client.Connect("srv", 25, false);
            Client.Authenticate("usr", "pass");
```

Can you show my what did I do wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The likeliest explanation is that the server is not available ;). So it's not a code problem, but a network problem...

Answer (score 0):

Is "srv" a valid hostname?  Try to ping the hostname in commandline.

And port 25 is usually the port for sending e-mails.

I would recommend verifying the port also.

Answer (score 0):

If you authenticate with username and password you need to pass `AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword` to `Authenticate`:

```
using(var client = New OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client())
{
   // Connect to the server
   client.Connect(Pop3Server, Pop3Port, false);
   // Authenticate towards the server
   client.Authenticate("usr", "pass", OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
   // Get the number of messages in the inbox
   int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();
}
```

Note that I've used using-statement which is always recommend when an onject implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

The port is wrong.

Kindly use the following ports for POP3: port 110 or port 995 for Secure SSL.

Also kindly check that 'srv' is a valid hostname which I think is wrong as well.